# Concept of integration and differentiation on any set?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am learning multivariable calculus. I would like to have 2 questions:

1. Concerning integration, I see that there is the definition of integration of a function from $X \to \mathbb{R}$ ($X$ is any set). Is there any concept of integration of a function from $X \to Y$ where $Y$ is an arbitrary set  ?
2. More generally, which is the condition of the set $X, Y$ for which we can define differentiation and integration for a function $f: X \to Y$ ? What makes integration and differentiation "so special" that it requires some conditions to be defined ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For integration, you need $X$ to be a measure space, and $Y$ to be a vector space of some kind, preferably a Banach space, like $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{R}^n$ or $\Bbb{C}$ or $\Bbb{C}^n$. Didn't you already ask a similar question for differentiation?

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Could you please briefly explain why we need these requirement for the integration calculation to be defined ? Thank you very much!

Comment: if integration is even remotely supposed to resemble what we learn about Riemann integrals, we need a notion of "size of a set" (this is like the $\Delta x$ in Riemann sums). THat's why we need the domain to be a measure space. Next, the very notion of "sum" in "Riemann sums" (and the fact that we wish to multiply be scalars) means that the target space ought to be a vector space.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thank you for your response. Can we take $Y$ to be the vector space like $P$ (the vector space of all polynomials with real coefficients) ? Intuitively, I think no because it does not make sense, but i wonder whether if it is technically possible or not ?

Comment: a bare vector space alone probably isn't enough, because we usually first define the integral of simple functions, and then use them to approximate other types of functions. Approximation means we need limits, which means we need a topology on the target space. So, something like a topological vector space, or better yet, a Banach space would be ideal. So, the full space of polynomials might not be suitable, but certain subspaces (finite-dimensional ones) or for example, $c_0$, which is the space of sequences which vanishes at $\infty$ or something like that can be used for integration.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: thanks for your kind response! I am wondering also that if we are able to define the integration on a set $Y$ which can be different from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, and, as for me, $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is the set of real number (or hyperreal to be said), an integration on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ makes sense to me (as we can, maybe, interpret it as the area under the curve, or the volume, ...). So, if the set $Y$ is not "set of number", then do you think that the integration defined on $Y$ make sense ? I'm so confused at this point.

Comment: I would suggest you go step by step and learn the definitions first.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Hi, thank you! Could you please suggest me a book that discuss about the condition of the set $X, Y$ in which we can define integration ? Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know of any book which talks about that explicitly. But just take any real analysis book which talks about measure theory/integration. Then after reading the definitions ask yourself where the various structure is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would just like to point out that "defining integration" is already a vague concept; usually we would like to construct our definitions for a specific purpose. In the case of Riemann integration the symbol $\int$ roughly corresponds to the opposite of differentiation. In real analysis, we redefine the symbol $\int$ with *a specific purpose in mind*, namely making the class of integrable functions complete.

For example, I can "define" integration as $\int:\bf{R}\rightarrow \bf{R}$ by $x\mapsto x^2$ so that now $\int\,f(x)\,dx = (f(x))^2$. I can't think of a situation where this would be desired, but long story short is you can define $\int$ however you want and take it over any set and map into any set. But I know this isn't really what you are asking.

With this in mind:

1. The Lebesgue integral is fairly general and defines $\int:X\rightarrow \bf{C}$ for $X$ a measure space, which informally means you can make precise the notion of "size". Other "generalized" integrals you may be interested in are the Bochner integral and the Bessel potential.
2. What makes differentiation and integration special is that **we have defined them to be special**. I find many students starting out in math have thoughts along these lines, and I certainly had them myself.

To elaborate on this second point. The notion of differentiation you have learned is **defined** in a very special way, and all of the resulting theory is a consequence of our **definition**, not a consequence of some independent thing called "differentiation"; "differentiation" is just what we call (in calculus at least) the operation of taking a limit of a difference quotient.

So now you want to generalize this thing called "differentiation"; there isn't some straightforward way that mathematicians generalize notions. For example there is a generalization known as Sobolev differentiation or weak differentiation which is *very specifically* defined to capture one aspect of derivatives, namely that it is the opposite operation of integration. We define a Sobolev derivative by noting that we can integrate "bad" functions, but can only differentiate $C^1$ functions meaningfully (in the sense you've learned in calculus). The Sobolev derivative says that any function which is the integral of a "bad" function has that function as it's Sobolev derivative. This class of functions turns out to be much larger than $C^1$, and is the proper context in which to talk about differential equations.

There is another notion of "fractional differentiation" which, depending on your perspective, further generalizes Sobolev differentiation or agrees with the notion for differentiation of integer order. The point being that this is yet another "generalization", and that these generalizations don't even mess with the domain and range yet!

Long story short: technically yes, but in general when generalizing definitions you would like a specific purpose in mind.